# How can I get a Live-Feed of the comments on my facebook page?

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, nlp

I'm hosting a facebook page with a little more than 100k likes. I'd like to set up a constant feed of all the comments under my posts but from what I've researched there is no such thing doing this in Python.

At the end of the day I'd like to automatically check for "angry" comments and I would like my script to highlight those.

Is there a module, online tool or anything else that does this kind of stuff?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _“Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.”_

Comment: Using Webhooks and subscribing to the feed connection of the page might work, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page/#feed